I tried to install strapi to refine dev: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addBreadcrumb')
Node.js v20.12.2
npm@10.5.2
Describe the bug:
After to run this command:
npx create-strapi-app@latest pdf-invoice-generator --quickstart

npm ERR! Node.js v20.12.2

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Tarek\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-04-16T19_07_56_753Z-debug-0.log
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'addBreadcrumb')
    at C:\Users\Tarek\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2d56dd13733e9da7\node_modules\@strapi\generate-new\dist\utils\usage.js:36:31
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at Module.captureStderr (C:\Users\Tarek\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2d56dd13733e9da7\node_modules\@strapi\generate-new\dist\utils\usage.js:35:37)    
    at createProject (C:\Users\Tarek\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2d56dd13733e9da7\node_modules\@strapi\generate-new\dist\create-project.js:133:17)       
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async createQuickStartProject (C:\Users\Tarek\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_npx\2d56dd13733e9da7\node_modules\@strapi\generate-new\dist\create-quickstart-project.js:18:3)
PS C:\Users\Tarek\Desktop\Refine\blog-pdf-invoice-generator> 


A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Tarek\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-04-16T19_07_56_753Z-debug-0.log

What does the log file mentioned in the error say ?
Some things i suggest:

try clearing the npm cache
Make sure that npm and node are upto date
installing strapi as a global dependency


I didn't have a problem while creating strapi, @msks-tanmay has good suggestions.
But there is something I don't understand, npx create-strapi-app@latest pdf-invoice-generator -quickstart does not generate a Refine project, it creates the Strapi CMS. So I don't understand how you got an error about Refine.
